# Pass Bash array in cURL POST call in Shell script

Tags: sql, bash, shell, curl

I am trying to do a curl call in my shell script where i want to pass the result of sql in data.

```
taleResult = `isql -S$envServer -U$USERNAME -h -b << ENDSQL | grep -vE "^Password: $"
$PASSWORD
set nocount on
GO
USE db_cfg
GO
SELECT tablename from MyTable
GO
ENDSQL`
```

Table result looks like `TableA TableB TableC`

```
liveCalculators=()
if echo "$tableResult"; then
            for line in $tableResult
            do
                MessageLog "Table is $line"
                liveCalculators+=(\"$line\")
            done
endif
```

Please assume I have result stored in array as `liveCalculators`

```
curl_response=` curl_response=`curl -k -X POST "https://myapiurl" \
                -H "accept: */*" \
                -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                -w ";%{http_code}" \
                -d "@/dev/stdin" <<EOF
                 { "keys": [],, "calcs": ${liveCalculators[@]}}
                EOF`
`
```

I get Bad Request as error

Please suggest what can be done to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this :

```
myFlatArr=$(printf '%s\n' "${liveCalculators[@]}" | paste -sd',')
curl -k -X POST "https://myapiurl" \ 
    -H "accept: */*" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -w ";%{http_code}" \
    -d "@/dev/stdin" <<EOF
{ "keys": [], "calcs": [ $myFlatArr ] }
EOF
```

Comment: I tried
 curl_response=`curl -k -X POST "https://myaoiurl" \
                -H "accept: */*" \
                -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                -w ";%{http_code}" \
                -d "@/dev/stdin" <<EOF
                 { "keys": [], "calcs": ${liveCalculators[@]}}
                EOF`

Comment: It didnt work actually

Comment: Can you edit your original post to show us what is the bash array ?

Comment: Previous one also worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you have `jq` installed, try this :

```
curl_response="$(curl -k -X POST "https://myapiurl"\
    -H "accept: */*"\
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"\
    -w ";%{http_code}"\
    -d "$(jq -cn '{"keys": [], "calcs": $ARGS.positional}' --args "${liveCalculators[@]}")"
)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array output is not encapsulated as a valid JSON, so how about this:

```
curl_response=$(curl -k -X POST "https://myapiurl" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"keys\": [], \"calcs\": \"${liveCalculators[@]}\" }" -w ";%{http_code}")
```

In addition, the output of the array `liveCalculators` is a BASH list, and you might need to do some parsing and search/replace, to convert it to a valid JSON list..